# How to deploy play framework project in ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, playframework, typesafe-activator

I am using `IntelliJ` IDE for the development and started the project using `Play 2.x` framework instead of `activator`:

[image]

Now I want to deploy this project to `EC2-Ubuntu` but to do that everyone is suggesting to install the `Typesafe activator` which will not work in my case.

I tried to follow the official documentation but they are also [redirecting](https://www.playframework.com/download) to download "play with activator". Is there any other way to deploy it instead of converting the whole project to `typesafe activator`?

Comment: what's the problem you encountered??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne To run the activator project you must have activator library in your project root folder but when you created a project without using activator template (through IntelliJ play framework plugin ) library is missing and AFAIK you can only deploy the project through typesafe activator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The play has a deployment system , you need to read the documentation to prepare the project in the right way , but basically you had used the command:

- `activator dist
- unzip file in `target/universal/file.zip`
- `file.sh  in bin folder

`[Deploy documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying)

Comment: I read the deployment instruction but I need to install the play framework on server. right? I couldn't even find the link for installation. The link I found is "https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole" which is focusing on activator

Comment: No you don't need to install play. The zip file created by the `dist` task has everything included except java ([as the documentation states](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Using-the-dist-task)). Just follow the instructions for dist task from the docs.

Comment: The zip file create by the dist, has on folder bin 2 files (.sh, .bat), you need only jvm install on server.